# How can I put a password onto my SSRS Dashboard Report?

Tags: variables, reporting-services, passwords

I have a Dashboard report that I have built in SSRS. I have a drop down that allows you to select team 1 , 2 or 3. (As Variables)

Is there any way that I can put 3 different passwords on the report so team 1 can only access there own and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - using windows authentication.

Create new reports linked to the original (within the SSRS dashboard) and have the permissions of those reports be set so that only Users in group 1 can see report A; group 2 can see report B etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set up a hidden parameter if you want or visible that pulls from a query. Build the query for the parameter as a case statement or pull from a table where you have the data.

```
SELECT group FROM groups WHERE userId = @UserId
```

In the report populate the @UserId parameter from the built in field =User!UserID. and that will only display the group that the user is in.